# Outlook.com css resetting itself to mobile view all the time

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, outlook-web-access

I've had this issue for years and i'm the only person it's affecting. I'm documenting this because i can't find anyone talking about it on the internet

When i load outlook.com and sign in with my organisation details it's loading the mobile css everytime.

Steps

1. Opening up in MS Edge Version 104.0.1293.47 (Official build) (64-bit)
2. Load outlook.com and sign in
3. Load Dev Tools. Right Click Refresh button | Empty Cache and Hard Refresh
4. page loads in desktop mode.
5. refresh page.
6. page loads with mobile css

I've just attempted inside a chrome browser Version 104.0.5112.81
and it's not reproducing. So therefore it's something inside my edge browser.

I've just moved to another machine. Edge is same version. Behaviour doesn't reproduce.
Opening an inprivate window and doesn't reproduce.

There is something wrong with my profile.
I'm logged into my profile on the other machine.
I'm going to log out of my profile. But i need to submit this question.
I'll come back.
thanks superuser for being my notepad cache

Answer (score 0):

I removed my profile on my main machine and now i don't have the problem.

Thanks superuser for forcing me to explain myself and thus fixing my own problem